# What is the percentage sign displayed in code completion in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently started using Eclipse IDE for Java. In code completion, there is a percentage sign displayed alongside some of the functions. I cannot figure out what it means.

A screenshot for the same

[image]

The eclipse edition is seen as

[image]

Can someone explain what this % sign means here ?

Comment: @jeroen :  this is duplicate. add the link to this question and please close it.

Comment: Look at the top of your question.